# Running Total with running subtraction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've used running total in stored procedure in sql server 2008 and I've passed a list of ids. Now the problem is, I am getting sum of all the ids.

What I want is to get sum individually of the ids passed in list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sql server 2012 has build in running sum. Upgrade or include your current code

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: We can if you provide some sample data and expected output in your question along with any current TSQL code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwGwR.png

Comment: @SamStha no screenshots, Include the code, testdata and expected outcome in your question. When we try to solve it, we prefer to be able to cut and paste your testdata

Comment: is it okay if I comment down my stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table #t ( Ordid int primary key , Receiptqty int , Issueqty int)

    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (1,2577,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty) values (2,2577,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (3,7903,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (4,7893,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (5,7920,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (6,7922,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (7,6903,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (8,7920,0)
    insert #t(Ordid,Receiptqty,Issueqty)  values (9,7922,0)

    --select * from #t order by Receiptqty 

    -- Running Total for SQL Server 2008 R2 and Earlier Version

    SELECT Receiptqty, Issueqty,
    (SELECT SUM(Receiptqty-Issueqty)
    FROM #t T2
    WHERE T2.Ordid <= t1.Ordid) AS RunningTotal
    FROM #t T1
    GO

    drop table #t
```